# Modify iptables firewall via web page

Tags: linux, iptables, web

I need for support personnel to be able to open firewall holes via the web.  I know this is a permissions nightmare but I have to do it.  I have gotten as far as creating a perl program which can do it, but when I run an iptables-restore command from a perl script run from apache through the web I get,

```
 FATAL: Module ip_tables not found. ... 
 iptables-restore v1.4.3.1: 
 iptables-restore: unable to initialize table 'filter' ...
```

I use iptables all the time on this box but apparently without needing the ip_tables module.  If I run the same script from the console as root there is no problem.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Are you running this via sudo? or what?

Comment: No.  But I have this as the first line of perl: #!/usr/bin/perl -wT  ... then I set the environment ... $ENV{'PATH'} = '/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/var/www/cgi-bin:/scripts:';

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest running the perl script using lighthttpd or something similar that will be setup to run as root rather then apache, and also listen on a non-standard port like 12345.

Here is a howto on configurating lighthttpd with perl:
http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/lighttpd-howto-setup-cgi-bin-access-for-perl-programs.html

Also don't forget to comment out server.username and server.groupname in lighthttpd.

To get the security a little better would be good to introduce at least http authentication and limit the IP's that can access this port.

Comment: Thanks :) can lighthttpd run simultaneously with apache?

Comment: nevermind ... a quick google search indicates it can ... thanks for the info

Comment: Sure it can. Just configure it not to run on the same ports as apache.

Answer (score 1):

I would deploy WebMin for this.

Comment: WebMin used to have a variety of security holes ... is it safe now?

Comment: It's a philosophical question, @xivix, nothing can be considered absolutely safe and there can hardly be a piece of software with no security holes. Moreover, no offence, but I doubt a DIY solution is going to be safer.

Comment: how would I do this via WebMin?

Comment: That's intuitive - just log-in to WebMin and find the place. I used to do it once, had no problems finding it (but can't remember it now - I need to see it to find it).

Comment: I cannot give support personnel access to webmin which in turn would give them total control of the server.

Comment: I've said it before, anytime I investigate a system compromise the first things I look for are webmin and phpmyadmin. Webmin isn't just bad because it has a terrifying history, but also because it indicates lack of professional ability and/or pride.